# How to find my exe is running in local or network shared folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How to construct root path from registry editor when execute program in web server,while executing in local path i am getting as ""C:\Users\Desktop\SPHelper.exe" "%1""  but in web server i am getting in this format ""webserver\Dot net upload\SPHelper.exe" "%1".

How to construct root path in web server in complete format? for example`("\\webserver\Dot net upload\SPHelper.exe""%1")`

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
We can use this to find the Location
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location